# Dependent dropdown menu not connecting

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to make a dependent dropdown menu in laravel and ajax. I have two tables, district and thanas. Districts can have many thanas. I am trying to make something when i select a district, only the thanas under that district will show.

```
 $data=Thana::select('name','id')->where('district_id',$request->id)->take(100)->get();
        return response()->json($data);//
```

This is supposed to return the thana name and id which matches the requested district id, but this is failing for some reason. The correct district_id is being shown though.

This is my controller code.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\District;
use App\Thana;
use App\Atm;
class AtmController extends Controller
{
   public function atmfunct(){
        $atmdistrict=District::all();
        $atmthana=Thana::all();//get data from table
        return view('MasterForms.atmlist',compact('atmthana','atmdistrict'));//sent data to view

    }

    public function findThanaName(Request $request){


        //if our chosen id and products table prod_cat_id col match the get first 100 data 

        //$request->id here is the id of our chosen option id
        $data=Thana::select('name','id')->where('district_id',$request->id)->take(100)->get();
        return response()->json($data);//then sent this data to ajax success
    }



}
```

This is the part where I am connecting the jquery request.

```
<span>District: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="districtt" id="district_id">

        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
        @foreach($atmdistrict as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>

    <span>Thana Name: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="name">

        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Thana Name</option>
        @foreach($atmthana as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>




</center>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change','.districtt',function(){
         console.log("hmm its change");

            var district_id=$(this).val();
             console.log(district_id);
            var div=$(this).parent();

            var op=" ";

            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('findThanaName')!!}',
                data:{'id':district_id},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log('success');

                    //console.log(data);

                    //console.log(data.length);
                    op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>chose division</option>';
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    op+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
                   }

                   div.find('.name').html(" ");
                   div.find('.name').append(op);
                },
                error:function(){
                        console.log('error');
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So which part of your code you think is failing? Please give us more information about:

1. What does `'{!!URL::to('findThanaName')!!}'` look like?
2. Raw JSON example when `'{!!URL::to('findThanaName')!!}'` is accessed with  `district_id`
3. Show us your route file which contains `'{!!URL::to('findThanaName')!!}'`.

I will edit my answer according to the information you give later. I don't have enough reputation to give a comment yet :p